# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest with Method Head allocate too much RAM

Tags: command-line, memory, powershell, download, oom

**Problem found on server with Powershell v 4.0**
*(server with Powershell 5.1 they do not seem affected by the same problem)*

This a strange behavior of **Invoke-WebRequest** command.

Take this example:

For some reason, I need to know the file size before download it on my server.

Then I use the following commands:

```
$WebClient = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $element -Method Head -Credential $Cred
$filesize = $webClient.Headers.'Content-Length'
```

The problem is *before send* $WebClient request Powershell use (for Commit RAM) about 120MB, but *after the request* powershell enlarge your RAM a the file $filesize value (example remote file is 800MB, new Commit RAM is 920MB).

When you work with Powershell WinRM session limited at 1GB of RAM this can be a problem. (OOM)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Invoke-WebRequest` with the `HEAD` method to get just the headers and not download anything. If the resource you're requesting has a known length, then you'll get a `Content-Length` header which you can use:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Head).Headers.'Content-Length'
```

Just note that not all servers return the `Content-Length` header for
all requests. In that case you will need to use your above method
which reads the entire file,
although it's slower and wasteful of memory.

You can also interface directly to the Windows DLLs that do Internet requests,
either
[WinINet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/about-wininet)
(not available on Windows Server), or using
[Windows HTTP Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinHttp/winhttp-start-page).

Comment: If you send and HEAD request, and the remote system know the Content-Lenght of the resource request, Powershell (and all other language) not receive the file, but only a the HEAD with the Content-Lenght inside. So, I guess, it makes no sense to allocate as much memory as the file is large if I only do a head request.

Comment: Actually you are right and there is a way using `Invoke-WebRequest`. I rewrote my answer.